# Lucene substring matching

Tags: lucene

What is the best way to check if `String a` is part of `String b` in Lucene. For example: `a = "capital"` and `b = "Berlin is a capital of Germany"`. In this case `b` contains `a` and fits the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be treated as some field contains certain term or not.
The basic TermQuery should be enough to solve your problem, in most analyzers,  "Berlin is a capital of Germany" will be analyzed as "berlin", "capital" "germany"(if you use the basic stop words)

```
// code in Scala
new TermQuery(new Term("contents", "capital"))
```

you can also use PhraseQuery to solve your problem(though, your problem is not the most suitable scenario for PhraseQuery).

```
val query = new PhraseQuery();
query.add(new Term("contents", "capital"))
```

Lucene In Action 2nd, **3.4 Lucene’s diverse queries** introduces all kinds of Query used in Lucene. I suggest you have a read and that might help.